# Como acessar o valor de um atributo private em uma classe em Java sem um método público?

Tags: java, java-8, reflexão

Como posso acessar o valor de um atributo private em uma classe, de uma classe em outro pacote, sem utilizar um método de acesso, como um getter?

```
class Person{
   private String name = "Someone";
}
```

**Por que alguém faria isso?**

Uma das razões é que você pode precisa serializar objetos, como o [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) faz, transformando os valores dos campos da classe em JSON. Posso acessar usando getters do campo, mas caso eu não os tenha, ou eles não sigam o padrão JavaBeans, no exemplo `getName`, como eu acesso o valor do campo diretamente. O próprio Jackson permite que se configure se você quer acessar através de setters e getters, ou com os campos diretamente. Existe um ganho real de performance.

Comment: Acredito que não pq furaria todo a ideia do encapsulamento, mesmo que envolvendo herança e outras paradas.

Comment: Sem reflection você só ira conseguir acessar o atributo se estiver no mesmo pacote da classe, caso contrário não, até mesmo pq isso não faz muito sentido.

Comment: O campo name é private. Se a classe que quiser acessar estiver no mesmo pacote, ela não pode acessar o campo name, pois este é private, ele teria de ser package private. O ponto é, em que cenário, reflection não funciona?

Comment: Sem reflection não é possível...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Expose {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Field secretField = null;
        try {
            secretField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        secretField.setAccessible(true); // break the lock!
        try {
            String wasHidden = (String) secretField.get(person);
            System.out.println("person.name = " + wasHidden);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
            // this will not happen after setAcessible(true)
            System.err.println(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

*Exemplo adaptado de* https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/09-pythonic-obj/private/Expose.java

Comment: Perceba que eu pergunto se é sempre possível fazer isso. E não é sempre possível faze-lo. Queria saber por que em certos casos este código que você postou pode não funcionar. Vou detalhar mais a pergunta.

Comment: Bom, como você colocou (depois que eu respondi inclusive) que reflection não lhe ajuda, pode desconsiderar minha resposta.

Comment: Olá @drgarcia1986, simplifiquei minha pergunta, a mesma estava confusa, agora acho que está mais clara, e sim sua resposta atende perfeitamente a questão atual. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Legal @FilipeGonzagaMiranda fico feliz que tenha ajudado